# How do I connect appium inspector to a running session

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I'm working on test automation that uses appium for it's connection to an android device. Occasionally, I end up in a spot where I'm debugging why a test has failed, and it is because a developer has changed something so my id no longer works, or the xpath has changed, or some other weirdness where a developer changed something and didn't consider the tester (like that's never happened).

I would like to be able to run my automation, and right before the query runs, hit a breakpoint, and then I start the appium inspector and look at the page from there. It takes a long time for me to stop debugging, restart appium, then manually execute the test case to get me back into the same position I was in while debugging just to be able to see what the debug id's are on the app.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is to unplug and plug yet your device, then run uiautomatorviewer.exe in order to inspect the current view..

Comment: Yup yup. That worked like a champ. Thanks very much, langme :)